# Can't make Airflow use postgresql ( rds ) instead sqlite

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I Installed airflow on 3 ec2 nodes: webserver, scheduler and worker, i set same config to `/airflow/airflow.cfg` at all 3 nodes, configuration of DB is next `sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:password@rdsdatabaseaddreess.com/airflow`. 
After that i restarted service `airflow` and execute command `airflow initdb`

```
ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-143 airflow]$ /usr/local/bin/airflow initdb
DB: sqlite:////airflow/airflow.db
[2019-11-21 01:39:30,325] {db.py:368} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
WARNI [airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.LoggingMixin] empty cryptography key - values will not be stored encrypted.
Done.
```

However airflow still using `sqlite` `DB: sqlite:////airflow/airflow.db`

Please advice.
With best regards.

Comment: Is `/airflow/airflow.cfg` the absolute path of the configuration file in which you set `sql_alchemy_conn`?

Comment: Same problem. It reads config (e.g. I can change Executor) but it still use only sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I find a solution: the setting `sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:██████████@rdsdatabaseaddreess.com/airflow` must be in section `[core]`. It is mentioned in the [official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/howto/set-up-database.html#database-uri). However, it is located in section `[database]` in the example config.

So, finally, my settings look like this:

```
[core]
executed = LocalExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:████████@rdsdatabaseaddreess.com/airflow


[database]
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:████████@rdsdatabaseaddreess.com/airflow
```